# Not printing same output

Tags: java, debugging, fitness, hill-climbing

Simply not printing the same output as the line above and I can't figure out why this is happening, I've noticed that it's printing the last N numbers from the end backwards, whatever i input into the parameter it prints that amount a second time.

Here's the main

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    ScalesSolution s1 = new ScalesSolution(11);
    s1.println();
    ScalesSolution s2 = new ScalesSolution(s1.GetSol());
    s2.println();
}
}
```

Heres the ScalesSolution Class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class ScalesSolution {
private String scasol;

public void print() {
    System.out.print(scasol);
}

// Display the string with a new line
public void println() {
    print();
    System.out.println();
}



public String GetSol()
{
    return scasol;
}
}
```

Heres the randomOther Class

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class randomOther {
// Shared random object
static private Random rand;

// Create a uniformly distributed random integer between aa and bb inclusive
static public int UI(int aa, int bb) {
    int a = Math.min(aa, bb);
    int b = Math.max(aa, bb);
    if (rand == null) {
        rand = new Random();
        rand.setSeed(System.nanoTime());
    }
    int d = b - a + 1;
    int x = rand.nextInt(d) + a;
    return (x);
}

// Create a uniformly distributed random double between a and b inclusive
static public double UR(double a, double b) {
    if (rand == null) {
        rand = new Random();
        rand.setSeed(System.nanoTime());
    }
    return ((b - a) * rand.nextDouble() + a);
}
static public ArrayList<Double> ReadNumberFile(String filename) {
    ArrayList<Double> res = new ArrayList<Double>();
    Reader r;
    try {
        r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        StreamTokenizer stok = new StreamTokenizer(r);
        stok.parseNumbers();
        stok.nextToken();
        while (stok.ttype != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
            if (stok.ttype == StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER) {
                res.add(stok.nval);
            }
            stok.nextToken();
        }
    } catch (Exception E) {
        System.out.println("+++ReadFile: " + E.getMessage());
    }
    return (res);
}
}
```

Here is the issue the Output:

```
00101001010101101011001011010101101001011010001011010010101101001001011010010
01011010010
```

I believe that both outputs should be the same and I see that there is a problem here, not sure why they aren't

Comment: Please provide a smaller example which still reproduces the error. Say, by removing some functions. Also, I see that you use `Random` in the code and seed it with current time, please get rid of randomness as well (e.g. by seeding it with constant data, or, even better, by removing dependency on random at all and using hard-coded consts).

Comment: i am unsure on how to edit it like that :s

Comment: Check out StackOverflow's tutorial on [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you don't know what the issue is, how do you expect anyone else to? What are you expecting?

Comment: @DevilsHnd hi sir i know the problem the output are different when they should be the same, i don't know why they are different though thats my issue that i'm having, i was hoping someone here knew what is going on and could help me

Comment: Your output lines are fine.. Just the way you have printed is messy..

Comment: @anacron Hi SIR so what would I need to do to make both outputs the same, what could I change because i don't know whats making it so horrible!

Comment: Why not just use System.out.println(s1.getSol()) instead of ...print and println?

Comment: @Galfi, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that the way your are using `System.out.print` inside your `RandomBinaryString(int n)` is causing confusion. It is printing and appending to the String `s`. Try to avoid that. Replacing the `System.out.print(s += '0');` and `System.out.print(s += '1');` with `s += '0';` and `s += '1';`in the `RandomBinaryString` will fix your output.

Use the snippet below in your code:

```
private static String RandomBinaryString(int n) {
    String s = new String();

    // Code goes here
    // Create a random binary string of just ones and zeros of length n
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int y = randomOther.UI(0, 1);
        if (y == 0) {
            s += '0';// this line here was changed
        } else {
            s += '1';// and this line here was changed too
        }
    }

    return (s);
}
```

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks.... wow thanks so much, its funny because I just forgot to remove this from my previous day and I FORGOT to re-remove it .-.

Comment: Glad it helped!